# What are the differences between the React Native IDEs Exponent and Deco?

Tags: react-native, ide

I'm looking into what IDE to use to build a React Native mobile application and am not sure what the difference between Deco https://www.decosoftware.com/ and Exponent https://getexponent.com/ is